# Having a map of Set in Java 8, how I can put all the values in one set?

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, set, java-stream

I have a `Map<String, Set<String>>`. I want all the values from this Map in a new `Set<String>` using the streams API. I was able to get a `Set<Set<String>>`, but what I want is all the values of all the sets from my map, in one Set. Is that possible using streams?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at `flatMap()`.

Answer (score 11):

Here you go:

```
Set<String> allStrings = map.values()
   .stream()
   .flatMap(Set::stream)
   .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: map.values represents already a set. so map.values() is sufficient. The key is lost.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution can be also :

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
map.values().forEach(set::addAll);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Stream.collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) method to achieve this:

```
Set<String> set = map.values().stream()
        .collect(HashSet::new, HashSet::addAll, HashSet::addAll);
```

If you need to be more flexible you should use the [`Stream.flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) solution.